# Linq simple XML snippet to non-anonymous type

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, anonymous-types

I am trying to parse this piece of XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
 <DagUren>
   <Chauffeur>Vincent</Chauffeur>
   <AanmeldTijd>4 dec. 2012 09:05:42</AanmeldTijd>
   <Gewerkt>04:42</Gewerkt>
 </DagUren>
```

I created a DagUren class that contains strings with Chauffer, AanmeldTijd, Gewerkt, etc.

```
        DagUren eenDagUren
            = (from du in doc.Element("DagUren")
               select new DagUren
               {
                   Chauffeur = du.Element("Chauffeur").Value,
                   Gewerkt = du.Element("Gewerkt").Value,
                   Pauze = du.Element("Pauze").Value,
                   AanmeldTijd = du.Element("AanmeldTijd").Value,
               }
         );
```

The compiler respons with: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.  'Select' not found.

Please advice, i've spend quite some time on it rewriting, every guide is using a different approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that `Element()` does not return a collection of `XElement` it just returns a single object. Linq just queries collections of items, not single objects. So your solution would be:

```
XElement du = doc.Element("DagUren");
DagUren ennDagUren =
    new DagUren
        { 
            Chauffeur = du.Element("Chauffeur").Value,
            Gewerkt = du.Element("Gewerkt").Value,
            Pauze = du.Element("Pauze").Value,
            AanmeldTijd = du.Element("AanmeldTijd").Value
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `Select` is an extension for `IEnumerable`, but you are selecting single element. Make query on enumerable, and apply `SingleOrDefault` at the end:

```
 DagUren eenDagUren
            = (from du in doc.Elements("DagUren")
               select new DagUren
               {
                   Chauffeur = du.Element("Chauffeur").Value,
                   Gewerkt = du.Element("Gewerkt").Value,
                   Pauze = du.Element("Pauze").Value,
                   AanmeldTijd = du.Element("AanmeldTijd").Value,
               }).SinleOrDefault();
```

Or simply (thus you have only one node to parse, which is root). Consider also to use nodes casting, instead of reading `Value` properties:

```
 XElement root = doc.Root;
 DagUren eenDagUren = new DagUren() {
               Chauffeur = (string)root.Element("Chauffeur"),
               Gewerkt = (TimeSpan)root.Element("Gewerkt"),
               Pauze = (bool)root.Element("Pauze"), // e.g. 
               AanmeldTijd = (DateTime)root.Element("AanmeldTijd") });
```

Comment: Both answers adress the question right, I think the top one is a bit more clear for future visitors :)